# bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig in Symfony3

Tags: forms, symfony, templates

How can I install "`bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig,...` for my project on 3 version Symfony?

When I copy these files to my project I get error:

> 'Unexpected character "&"' (Twig_Error_Syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy or past these files, but instead configure the TwigBundle to use them as form templates, make this configuration in your `config.yml` file

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
```

Make sure that bootstrap is used in your application

Use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Or download it and use it in your application

Comment: When these files install in my project when I create new project Symfony3? P.S. I tried these steps. I load these files but get error...

Comment: They are by default included in the project, check here `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` and tell me if you found them